# Was the pardoned prostitute a Kafir?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, forgiveness

> Abu Huraira reported: The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “A prostitute had once been forgiven. She passed by a dog panting near a well. Thirst had nearly killed him, so she took off her sock, tied it to her veil, and drew up some water. Allah forgave her for that.”
>
> Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 3143, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2245

Cited from https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2012/09/30/prostitute-forgiven-kalb/

According to the hadith above, a woman who committed sins was forgiven by Allah (SWT) due to quenching the thirst of a panting dog. Yes, she was forgiven, but how come she was? Did she commit kufr or not? Allah does not forgive a person who is a kafir and doesn't repent. Is she a monotheistic prostitute?

Answer (score 4):

Zina and Kufr are different things, one does not imply the other. There is nothing in the given hadith that suggests that she was a Kafirah, rather a wording of the hadith explicitly states that she was from the Bani Israel, which suggests that she was a monotheist:

> بينما كلب يطيف بركية، كاد يقتله العطش، إذ رأته بغي من بغايا **بني إسرائيل**، فنزعت موقها فسقته فغفر لها به
>
> While a dog was circling a well, almost dying of thirst, one of the prostitutes of **the Children of Israel** saw it. She took off her shoe and used it to give water to it, and made it drink, and she was forgiven (by Allah) because of that.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3467) and  [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2245b)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Just because she is a prostitute doesn't mean she is a kafira. She may sined but didn't do kufur.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. Please consider answering the question instead of commenting on possible misinterpretation.